# JS regexp to find only 1 or 2 long digits

Tags: javascript, regex, web, digits

Here's my code:

```
var dayRegX      = new RegExp("\\b" + "\\d{1, 2}" + "\\b", "g");
if(!dayRegX.test(day.value)){
    alert('not good');
}
```

The test method returns false all the time, so I get the alert, why is that? It supposed to return true, if I type in a 1 or 2 long digit. Thanks

Comment: what happens if you do `var dayRegX = /\b\d{1,2}\b/`?

Comment: For whatever reason, the problem seems to be the space in `{1, 2}`. Remove it.

Comment: yeah that was the space, post an answer please, and m.buettner thank you as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful with spaces in regex, there shouldn't be a space between `1,` and `2`, plus it doesn't seem like you need the RegExp constructor there:

```
var regex = /\b\d{1,2}\b/g;
if ( !regex.test(day.value) ) { ... }
```